# How to apply python lamda function on categorical dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas

How can we apply a lambda function on this categorical dataframe? Note that the Grades are categorical. I am expecting those above C to 'Pass'. instead it shows 'Fail'.

```
import pandas as pd
dfg = pd.DataFrame(['A+', 'A', 'A-', 'B+', 'B', 'B-', 'C+', 'C', 'C-', 'D+', 'D'],
                  index=['excellent', 'excellent', 'excellent', 'good', 'good', 'good', 'ok', 'ok', 'ok', 'poor', 'poor'])
dfg.rename(columns={0: 'Grades'}, inplace=True)
dfg['Grades'] = dfg['Grades'].astype('category',
                             categories=['D', 'D+', 'C-', 'C', 'C+', 'B-', 'B', 'B+', 'A-', 'A', 'A+'],
                             ordered=True)
def Assess(row):
     if row>'C':
        return 'Pass'
     return 'Fail'

dfg['Asses'] = dfg.apply(lambda x: Assess(x.Grades), axis=1)

dfg
```

see result

```
Grades  Asses
excellent   A+  Fail
excellent   A   Fail
excellent   A-  Fail
good    B+  Fail
good    B   Fail
good    B-  Fail
ok  C+  Pass
ok  C   Fail
ok  C-  Pass
poor    D+  Pass
poor    D   Pass
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you were using `apply` passes a string into the function, not a categorical thing.

Instead, use a comparison operation on the series itself and allow Pandas to handle the categorical nature of it.

```
dfg.assign(Assess=dfg.Grades > 'C')

          Grades  Asses
excellent     A+   True
excellent      A   True
excellent     A-   True
good          B+   True
good           B   True
good          B-   True
ok            C+   True
ok             C  False
ok            C-  False
poor          D+  False
poor           D  False
```

---

You can follow that up with a `map` to get pass/fail

```
dfg.assign(Asses=dfg.Grades.gt('C').map({True: 'Pass', False: 'Fail'}))

          Grades Asses
excellent     A+  Pass
excellent      A  Pass
excellent     A-  Pass
good          B+  Pass
good           B  Pass
good          B-  Pass
ok            C+  Pass
ok             C  Fail
ok            C-  Fail
poor          D+  Fail
poor           D  Fail
```

---

If you truly want a `lambda` (I wouldn't), you need to create a dictionary that maps letter grades back to numeric values.

```
m = dict(map(reversed, enumerate(dfg.Grades.cat.categories)))
dfg.assign(Asses=dfg.apply(lambda row: 'Pass' if m[row.Grades] > m['C'] else 'Fail', 1))

          Grades Asses
excellent     A+  Pass
excellent      A  Pass
excellent     A-  Pass
good          B+  Pass
good           B  Pass
good          B-  Pass
ok            C+  Pass
ok             C  Fail
ok            C-  Fail
poor          D+  Fail
poor           D  Fail
```

Comment: Thanks @pirsquared. Would there be anyway to use lambda/apply to achieve this?

Comment: Very elegant. Thanks @piRSquared.

Answer (score 5):

Use:

```
dfg['Assess'] = np.where(dfg['Grades']>'C','Pass','Fail')
dfg
```

Output:

```
         Grades Assess
excellent     A+  Pass
excellent      A  Pass
excellent     A-  Pass
good          B+  Pass
good           B  Pass
good          B-  Pass
ok            C+  Pass
ok             C  Fail
ok            C-  Fail
poor          D+  Fail
poor           D  Fail
```

Comment: Again, you are selecting a second value, therefore evaluating a string and not using pd.Series categorical methods.  And, avoid if possible using apply with axis=1.  Best to find vectorize methods like `np.where` in this case.

Comment: Thanks @ScottBoston, Perfect Answer! I would never have thought about it. It would have been easier if it was SQL for me.

Comment: @MEdwin Yeah I, too, come from a SQL background.  However, I took a class on pandas two years ago and really learned the foundation of pandas.  This is critical to understand better ways of using python for data analysis.

Comment: good idea. Is it possible to use lambda/apply to achieve this?

Comment: @MEdwin this is a far superior approach to `apply`, as `apply` is just a thinly veiled wrapper around iteration, while `np.where` is vectorized

Comment: In the spirit of making something out of nothing.  "Vectorized" is often overplayed.  In many cases, the "vectorized" approach is a thickly veiled wrapper around iteration.  In some cases, there is an algorithmic approach that reduces the time complexity.  In this case, time complexity is not reduced but using `numpy.where` is still way faster.